# Remove the date/time in SQL script generated using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I generate scripts in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, it seems to insert the date/time in the script also.

For example:

```
USE [AdventureWorks]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vw_test]    Script Date: 18/01/2017 3:27:10 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
<rest of script goes here>
```

How can I remove that?

Comment: There's no such thing as enterprise manager in sql server 2008.  You mean management studio?

Answer (score 30):

Tools.. Options.. SQL Server Object Explorer..Scripting

Probably need to set "Include Descriptive Headers" = false

However, your question is unclear so this is a guess.

Comment: `Include Descriptive Headers = false` turned off comment/date generation, +1.

Comment: That worked!  In case anyone's wondering, this is useful if you're Checking-In auto-generated Create Scripts and don't want "'changes'" Checked-In simply due to a new "Script Date".  Btw, would you happen to (easily) know the SSMS or VS RegEx Find and Replace strings to remove these Script Dates Comments from existing Script Files?

Comment: Got the RegEx!  In SSMS, Find (with Alt+E enabled) "`^/\*\*\*\*\*\* Object:  .+Script Date: .+\*\*\*\*\*\*/.*$`" (without the quotes) and replace with nothing.  It will leave a blank line which is what would be there when "Include Descriptive Headers" = false.  NOTE: For some reason, the ".*" at the end is needed if you include the "/" at the end.  May be some trailing Unprintable Character after the last "/"?

Comment: Correction: "It will" *not* "leave a blank line" "when "Include Descriptive Headers" = false", so In SSMS, Find (with Alt+E enabled) "^/\*\*\*\*\*\* Object: .+Script Date: .+\*\*\*\*\*\*/.*\n" (without the quotes) and replace with nothing.   NOTE: The "\n" (by itself or as "\r?\n") is key to removing the line.  "$" and "\r?$" will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Tom's comment, I made the following powershell script "sqlpostproc.ps1" to post-process the sql into something much more git friendly, by converting it to UTF8 and replacing the date-embedded lines with simple separator lines.  This way your DIFFs will be brief and clear.

```
 (Get-Content .\script.sql) -replace '^/\*\*\*\*\*\* Object:  .+Script Date: .+\*\*\*\*\*\*/.*$', "`r`n`r`n-- ==========================================================================`r`n`r`n" | Out-File script.nodates.sql
 Get-Content .\script.nodates.sql | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 script.utf8.sql
```

I use the following batch file to execute the script:

```
 powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file sqlpostproc.ps1
 copy script.utf8.sql script.sql
 del script.nodates.sql
 del script.utf8.sql
```