# Generate Scripts Without Date

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the date/time in my sql script generated using EM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196920/remove-the-date-time-in-my-sql-script-generated-using-em)

*Database - Tasks - Generate Scripts*

I use this operation to generate database script and store it in the control versions system.  But this script have lines like this:

> /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[statuses]    Script Date: 01/19/2012
>   11:32:16 ******/

The date in such lines changes each time I created it.  Can I generate the database script without this lines?

Comment: How are you generating the script?

Comment: Database - MyDatabase - Right Mouse Click - Tasks - Generate Scripts

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Based om comments on the question, change the SSMS options...

Tools..Options..SQL Server Object Explorer..Scripting

Uncheck "Include Descriptive headers"

Comment: i was doing something similar with SMO in c# and stumbled into this question which gave me a hint.  For those who also stumble here: Under `ScriptingOptions` change `IncludeHeaders` to false.